# How to retain format in conversion by FFmpeg?

Tags: file, ffmpeg

Suppose the input file does not have filename extension. FFmpeg detects input file format, but how to use the same format for output file automatically?

Comment: Use the codec copy options.

Comment: Not directly possible. Either the format has to be specified or an extension given to the output file. 'codec copy' does not autoselect a muxer.

Comment: First fun ffprobe on the file. Then run ffmpeg using the correct output extension.

Answer (score 3):

Try this script. For an input file without an extension we use `ffprobe` to figure out a suitable extension, and tack it on to the output file.

Run it like `./script.sh input_file_wtithout_extension`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input_file="$1"
extension=$(ffprobe "$input_file" -show_entries format=format_name -v quiet |\
    grep -oP 'format_name=\K\w+')

output_file="$input_file".$extension
ffmpeg -y -i "$input_file" -strict -2 $options "$output_file"
```

Comment: Instead of re-encoding you can re-mux with `-map 0 -c copy` in the `ffmpeg` command. Also, you don't need `-strict -2` unless your `ffmpeg` is ancient and the AAC encoder is being used.

Comment: For my example video, `ffprobe` shows "format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2", which gives "mov" as the extension by your script. However, the input file is "mp4".

Comment: I also get `mov` for an "mp4" with the extension stripped. But it shouldn't matter. It is just a container format, and both containers can hold H264 with AAC audio, for example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_File_Format tells: "Because both the QuickTime and MP4 container formats can use the same MPEG-4 formats, they are mostly interchangeable in a QuickTime-only environment. MP4, being an international standard, has more support. This is especially true on hardware devices, such as the Sony PSP and various DVD players; on the software side, most DirectShow and Video for Windows codec packs include an MP4 parser, but not one for QTFF."

Comment: `mediainfo --Inform='General;%Format/Extensions%'` tells "mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p 3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma f4v" for the file, but it tells the same even if I convert the file to ".mov" using `ffmpeg`.

Comment: This might fail on MKV files. I'm getting format_name=matroska,webm   and unless I'm misreading the grep, that'll throw all of that on the end